# Erro ao enviar e-mail no Laravel 5.7 - Swift_TransportException

Tags: php, laravel, email

Olá,

Estou tentando fazer um envio de e-mail usando o Laravel 5.7, e tive alguns problemas.

Escrevi uma view para o meu e-mail. Depois, mando enviar o e-mail renderizado pelo Controller, da seguinte forma:

```
Mail::send('admin.eventos.pessoa', ['pessoa' => $pessoa], function ($message) use ($pessoa){
   $message->to($pessoa->email);
});
```

Configurei o meu e-mail no Laravel da seguinte forma, da forma como sempre faço nas aplicações de teste:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mx1.hostinger.com.br
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=mail@aureliocasoni.xyz
MAIL_PASSWORD=senha
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Além disso, configurei o arquivo mail.php, para resolver o erro anterior "stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
     * error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed", como foi descrito [nessa questão da versão inglesa do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30556773/how-to-fix-stream-socket-enable-crypto-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1).

```
'stream' => [
    'ssl' => [
        'allow_self_signed' => true,
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
    ],
],
```

Bem, depois chamo o método do controller que chama esse primeiro excerto que coloquei na pergunta. Esse controller é chamado via Post. Mas ao invés do e-mail ser enviado, recebo isso como resposta:

Swift_TransportException thrown with message "Expected response code 354 but got code "554", with message "554 5.5.1 Error: no valid recipients
""

O que pode ser isso?

**O que já tentei:**

1. Instalar a biblioteca guzzle;
2. Trocar a criptografia de TLS para SSL;
3. Verificar conexão do servidor.

Todos eles não deram certo.

Agradeço as respostas.

Answer (score -1):

Eu já apanhei muito para configurar esse tipo de conexão e cheguei a seguinte conclusão.

Crie e use contas Google para envio de e-mail, isso por que alguns servidores de e-mail não aceitam esse tipo de envio.

Lembrando que se usar um e-mail Gmail tem que liberar para usar aplicativos menos seguros

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=seuemail@gmail.com.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=suasenha
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Answer (score -1):

Você consegue enviar o e-mail se ele for o mesmo do .env

por ex:

```
 public function toMail($notifiable)
  {

    return (new MailMessage)->from('contato@seudominio.com', 'Ola!')
           ...
  }
```

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.hostinger.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=contato@seudominio.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=suasenha
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=
```

lembre de deixar o MAIL_ENCRYPTION em branco.

Answer (score -2):

Defina no seu `.env` `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS` e `MAIL_FROM_NAME` e o problema estará resolvido.